# Как сделать одностраничник на Drupal

Tags: drupal, page

У меня есть шаблон одностраничника.
Подскажите пожалуйста как каким образом натянуть его на Drupal чтобы получился Landing

Comment: установить все необходимые модули и запустить сайт))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На мой взгляд, Drupal - немного странный выбор для Landing Page.

Но, раз уж так надо, то:

1. Разворачиваете друпал
2. Создаете тему (на основе Вашего шаблона)

В принципе, все. Далее просто включаете тему и добавляете нужные модули.

Другие варианты:

Landing Page - по сути одностраничник, почему бы не оставить его просто html страничкой, которую залить на хостинг?

Существует множество Flat File CMS (файловые CMS, которым не требуется база данных). Возможно, это более, подходящее и легковесное решение для лендинга, которому нужна "админка".

Comment: Заказчик хочет друпал)

Comment: Каждому делу нужны свои инструменты. Задача профессионала - не только реализовать "мечту" заказчика. Так же, главное - донести до заказчика и объяснить, отличие одних технологий от других, грамотно обосновать, почему целесообразно использовать то, а не другое решение. Если же, заказчик все знает и все умеет, твердо убежден, что Drupal заточен под лендинги, задумайтесь, стоит ли с ним вообще сотрудничать!? Не будет ли Вам потом стыдно показать портфолио, в котором будет красоваться запись, "Я создал лендинг на Drupal"? Реально ли с такой записью в портфолио найти адекватного заказчика?

Comment: Если заказчик хочет Друпал, это говорит о его знаниях в этом вопросе. Почему бы не залить HTML и сказать что это Друпал? Он же все равно не поймет.

Comment: можно закрыть тему